# How to derive the chances of getting the Jackpot in NY Mega Millions with the given answer?

Tags: probability

The chances is 1 in 258,890,850: http://nylottery.ny.gov/wps/portal/!ut/p/c5/04_SB8K8xLLM9MSSzPy8xBz9CP0os_jggBC3kDBPE0MLC0dnA09vT0fLQDNvA0dfU30_j_zcVP1I_ShzXKoCgw30I3NS0xOTK_ULst0cAYmfjdU!/dl3/d3/L0lJSklna21BL0lKakFBRXlBQkVSQ0pBISEvNEZHZ3NvMFZ2emE5SUFnIS83X1NQVEZUVkk0MTg4QUMwSUtJQTlRNkswUVMwL3VOY3IwMTMwNDAwMDU!/?PC_7_SPTFTVI4188AC0IKIA9Q6K0QS0_WCM_CONTEXT=/wps/wcm/connect/NYSL+Content+Library/NYSL+Internet+Site/Home/Jackpot+Games/MEGA+MILLIONS/MegaMillions+-+Chances+of+Winning

How to derive the chances of getting the Jackpot in NY Mega Millions with the given answer? please check your answer!

Comment: I heard on Facebook that two people won the same big lottery with the same winning number.  Is this that lottery?  Does anyone know if this is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You choose 5  numbers from within  the set {$1,2,...,75$}, in $75C5=17259390$  ("75 choose 5") ways. Then you multiply by 15 , because you can choose the additional ball in 15 ways. Then you have $17259390)(15)=258890850$